# Ruby on Rails generate model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, scaffolding

So, I want to make my models render to json object so it can be used for a Android Device. I have all the models setup, but because I used the sccafold generate model call, I don't have any methods in the controller of the models... How do I generate the actual code, so that I can render the model in json?

I am using

```
$ rails --version
Rails 3.2.13
```

Comment: The answer can easily be found with a quick google search.

Answer (score 1):

From the Ruby on Rails guide:

```
render :json => @product
```

So, inside the generated controller you can do something like this:

```
def show
    @user = User.find( params[:id] )
    respond_to do |format|
        format.json{
            render :json => @user.to_json
        }
    end
end
```

Tip: You don’t need to call to_json on the object that you want to render. If you use the :json option, render will automatically call to_json for you.

You can find some examples on questions that have been answered previously:

- [In Rails, how do you render JSON using a view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088280/in-rails-how-do-you-render-json-using-a-view)
- [Rendering JSON in controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824551/rendering-json-in-controller)
- [Ruby on Rails - Render JSON for multiple models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318962/ruby-on-rails-render-json-for-multiple-models)

Comment: yeah but where do I put it if the code generated from scafollding is:
class PostsController < InheritedResources::Base
 before_filter :authenticate_user!
end

Comment: I edited the answer and added some code to give you a better idea of where this code is supposed to go.