# render multiple queries as json in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have two rails controller actions:

```
  def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    render json: @project,
      :only => [:id, :compilation_id],
      :methods => :track_name,
      :include => {
        :user => { :only => [:id, :email] }
      }
  end

  def list_users
    render json: User.select(:id, :email)
  end
```

I would like to render them both in one response.  What is the best way to go about doing this?  I tried using the `to_json` method as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318962/ruby-on-rails-render-json-for-multiple-models) but I read that that method is deprecated and I also noticed that it escapes the content which seems to be unnecessary.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did the answer solve your question?

Comment: @dgilperez- No, your answer did not address the issue of rendering two models in one response.  The info was useful, though, and I gave you an upvote.

Comment: Try jbuilder, I use it to render complicated json response all the time.

Answer (score 1):

For the cases where you need json structures complicated enough for `to_json` to look readable, I recommend to use **[active_model_serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers)** gem.

You can then define two serializer classes like this:

```
class ProjectSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :compilation_id

  has_many :users
end

class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :email
end
```

And then in your controller:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    render json: @project, serializer: ProjectSerializer, status: 200
  end
end
```

As a bonus track, you can even [cache the response](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/0-8-stable/lib/active_model/serializer.rb#L74)!

Answer (score 0):

The solution, of course, was pretty simple:

```
project = Project.select(:id, :compilation_id, :user_id, :genre_id, :ordering).find(params[:id])
render json: { :project => project,
               :users => User.select(:id, :email),
               :genres => Genre.select(:id, :name),
               :track_name => project.track_name
             }
```