# How can I render two objects using "render json:" in a Controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two objects that I want my index action to return, but I'm struggling to find the syntax to return them both at the same time.

```
def index
      last_day_for_jack = Tacobell.where(owner: "Jack")
      last_day_for_pete = Tacobell.where(owner: "Pete")
      render json: { last_day_for_jack last_day_for_pete }
  end
```

Comment: Make it an array, for example: `render json: [last_day_for_jack, last_day_for_pete]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails - Render JSON for multiple models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318962/ruby-on-rails-render-json-for-multiple-models)